# Need to show thousand of data in listview in qml without loading all data at same time

Tags: qt, qml

Hi i am using QT and QML. I am trying to write a programme which extracts thousand of data from sql database and display them in a listview in qml. The problem is that i want to show only 10 data for example in listview. The rest of data can be feeded to listview on scrolling down.

I have been advice to use proxy model however I have seen only examples which uses QSortFilterProxyModel in choosing some rows/column of data collection, which gives the result something else as it is simply filtering of data.

Please let me know a solution to this problem if possible please recommend or show me some example of such thing.

Please remember feeding data to listview on scrolling the bar down is very important as data instead of 1000's can later be in millions.

Thank You !!

Comment: I haven’t worked with QML, but if you use a custom model with `QListView`, it will only query the items it currently has to display. If you route that through a `QSortFilterProxyModel` that will at least load _all_ the data once, when you reset the model.

Comment: @Darklighter Thank You for the reply can you please elaborate out of 1000 of data how QlistView loads only the required number i.e. 10 of data and rest later.

Comment: because it knows which model indices are currently visible to the user (the scroll position) and will only query those

Comment: @Darklighter Thank You !!.  However QListView is related to ui.I am using QML does ListView in QML Will work in similar manner ?

Comment: i don’t know but i would think/hope so.

Answer (score 1):

See ListView's [documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-listview.html#details):

> Delegates are instantiated as needed and may be destroyed at any time.

ListView will only load as many items as it can fit within its bounds (+/- [cacheBuffer](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-listview.html#cacheBuffer-prop)). Since you're also using an SQL model, it should have no problems with very large data sets.

Comment: Thank You for the reply. I want to emphaise by saying i never said there is a problem with ListView loading 1000 of data items. My question is very simple I dont want to give thousand of data set values to ListView. I only want to give a certain number i.e. 10 in this case and want to feed remaining at later stage i.e. when scrolling down.

Comment: ListView queries the model for say 10 items if it needs to show 10 items. The only way it would query 1000 items is if you made the viewport 1000 items tall (or wide, for views with a horizontal orientation).